# DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH works on 2.2.2? Not caught by lint?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, backwards-compatibility, android-2.2-froyo

I have code that references DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH.  Android docs state that this is supported in API 9+.  The code in question is not affected by the TargetApi annotation.  My project's minSdkVersion is set to 7.  What's strange:

1. When I run the Lint tool on the project, it doesn't complain about the reference to DENSITY_XHIGH.
2. When I build and deploy to a 2.2.2 device (API 8), the code runs without flaw.  I put in debug statements to echo the value of DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH and see "320" (the correct value) in the log file.

What's going on?  Did this device manufacturer patch the 2.2.2 code to add this value?  That would explain why the package runs on that device, but what about the lint tool not catching the error?  Bug in the lint tool?

Edit:  I looked at the source code to 2.2, 2.2.1 and 2.2.2 and DENSITY_XHIGH isn't present in DisplayMetrics.java for any of them.

Comment: perhaps they did patched it, however I suggest you validate the version of the device before using it.

Comment: The code in question was actually doing something like "if density = HIGH || density = XHIGH then do ...".  So I just changed it to "if density >= HIGH do ...".